# Dot Notation vs Method Notation

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I'm diving into iOS programming and I'm having difficulty getting my head around the idea of Dot Notation and Method Notation.

As far as I understand it, Dot Notation can be used to invoke setters/getters on properties and is much more cleaner to write/read. Method Notation is used to send messages to objects to manipulate them etc.

Could someone give me a simple explanation as to why the following two statements are essentially different and one will compile but the other will instead fail due to a syntax error.

```
- (IBAction)digitPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
   NSString *digit = [sender currentTitle];

   self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingFormat:digit];
   self.display.text = self.display.text.stringByAppendingFormat:digit;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: the last line doesn't make sense, it has a syntax error

Comment: The item on the left is not a letter, sir?

Comment: I'm aware that the last line is syntactically incorrect, I'm looking for an explanation as to why these two lines are different. Why do the square brackets change the meaning of self.display.text? Why can't i use self.display.text.stringByAppendingFormat?

Comment: It's concerning that you were downvoted for using invalid code within a question demonstrating that you are a beginner with ObjC. Your question could have been clearer (you do by omission indicate that the last line of code compiles) but that's why we're here to help.

Comment: Not sure why this question got down voted other than it's not phrased very well. There is an issue here, it's actually pretty subtle and should be discussed. The answer from Ricard is very good re getters/setters and methods. And the answer from @Cirrostratus is very useful re more on methods. Edit your question in light of these and you've got a very useful question.

Comment: Dot notation is only valid for parameterless methods, or methods returning void but accepting only one parameter.  You maybe could write `self.display.text.stringByAppendingString = digit;`, but it would be a no-op, since the result would be thrown away.

Comment: I would like to add this link http://qualitycoding.org/dot-notation/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're entering into Objective-C development at an interesting time where old syntax is being used with new syntax. Dot syntax is syntactic sugar and there are some cases where you *can* use it but you should not.

The following is invalid syntax. Anything where you'd use a colon (besides setters or getters), you won't use dot notation.

```
self.display.text = self.display.text.stringByAppendingFormat:digit;
```

Also, you would use `stringByAppendingString`, not `stringByAppendingFormat`

You use dot notation for accessing variables, not for calling actions that will have effects.

**Correct:**
    `self.foo.attributeOfMyClass`

**Incorrect:**
    `self.foo.downloadSomethingFromAWebsite`

Ensuring you *always* use dot notation for accessing property values and you always use bracket notation (even when you don't *have to*) for calling action methods, your code will be much clearer upon a glance.

Comment: The following is invalid syntax. Anything where you'd use a colon, you won't use dot notation. <--- This is brilliant advice, thank you!

Comment: That's not entirely true--note that `[foo setBar:3];` involves a colon, but could be expressed in dot notation as `foo.bar = 3;`. The important distinction is that dot notation *may* used for accessors (methods that get or set properties), but not for anything else. Also note that if it confuses you, you need not use it at all.

Comment: well said, i totally agree

Comment: am I the only one who used method notation to resolve abnormal crashes?

Answer (score 6):

Dot notation is just shorthand for a specific kind of method--namely, accessors. You may use it in the following cases:

1. When setting a property: `foo.bar = 3;` is equivalent to `[foo setBar:3];`.
2. When requesting a property: in any case except the one above, `foo.bar` is equivalent to `[foo bar]`.

Dot notation is *only* shorthand--there is nothing magic about its relationship to properties. You could *theoretically* use dot notation to send any message that takes no arguments (`foo.doSomething`), but this would be *very very bad style*, as dot notation is intended for properties. Also note that if dot notation vs. square brackets is confusing you while you're learning, it's a perfectly valid choice to avoid dot notation altogether. It's just one shortcut you *may* use for accessors, if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your second statement is not correct. Objective C way to invoke methods (messages) is using the [instance message] syntax.
As you said, the dot notation is just to call getters and setters on class properties, but not messages, that's why your second statement is not correct. The two lines you may wanted to compare are:

```
self.display.text = [self.display.text stringByAppendingFormat:digit];
[[self display] setText:[[[self display] text] stringByAppendingFormat:digit]];
```

Note that the message stringByAppendingFormat has to be called the normal way.
The dot notation is just to write faster and not so many brackets, but it will execute exactly the same instructions once compiled.

Comment: So the main function for dot notation is purely for setting/getting and if I wanted to manipulate objects I should use method notation?  I'm coming from a Java background so the use of (.) to manipulate variables/objects is what I'm used to and so probably where I'm getting confused.

Comment: That's it. It is a bit messy when at the beginning, but then you will love it! :)

Comment: @Darryl: (So far as I'm aware) in Java, methods are much more "members" of their objects than in ObjC. There's an extra step of indirection here -- you send a message to an object, which consists of a "selector", and the object looks up the selector in its metaclass's method table.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason for using selector notation rather than dot notation is due to the dynamic language features in Objective C.  As an example, consider the following:

```
NSString *s = @"Hello World!";
NSLog(@"Length is %d", s.length);
```

This works as we would expect.  However, objects in Objective C may be passed around with type `id`.  Consider the following:

```
id s = @"Hello World!";
NSLog(@"Length is %d", s.length);
```

This won't compile, as `id` doesn't have a property called `length`.  The following will work, however:

```
id s = @"Hello World!";
NSLog(@"Length is %d", [s length]);
```

The reason this works is that Objective C knows about `NSString`, and so knows that there is some object type that responds to the selector `length`.  Of course, if you try the following:

```
id s = [[UIView alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Length is %d", [s length]);
```

Your code will compile correctly, but a runtime exception will occur (`unrecognized selector sent to instance`) as `UIView` does not have a `length` selector.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say we have the class `Class` with the variable `variableOne` we are going to use both notations.

**Dot notation** is the purest way to access a variable. It is also the way that bracket notation is most likely doing it behind the scenes. By typing `Class.variableOne`... `variableOne` is a part of `Class` and the "." after the class tells the compiler that it would like to access a part of the class--either a variable or a method.

**Bracket notation** is uses a method to access the variable. Let's say...

```
-(int) setVariable:x {
    self.variableOne = x;
}

-(int) showVariable {
    return self.variableOne
}
```

So when you're using bracket notation to set the variable `[variableOne setVariable:5]` or displaying the variable `[variableOne showVariable]` it calls the appropriate method.

*This is a very simple way to think of the difference, I realize another answer has already been accepted but perhaps this answer will explain it for someone who didn't understand another answer.*

Comment: Nicely put, I've gained much more experience in the nuances of Objective-C since I posted this but its always nice to go back and see alternative answers to old questions.

Answer (score 2):

When your code gets compiled, clang actually first takes all of your dot notation and turns it into method/bracket notation, so `self.display` and `[self display]` are exactly the same. Dot notation is actually fairly new as of Objective-C 2.0. It's simply for convenience.

Dot notation can only be used for properties, because doing something like you tried to do (which will not compile) gets cumbersome:

`self.display.text.stringByAppendingFormat:digit;`

It also wouldn't work for methods that take multiple arguments since you'd need to put spaces between arguments and suddenly the line of code would look awkward and hard to read.

Comment: Dot notation can actually be used for any parameterless method (`tableView.reloadData;`), and can be used like an lvalue anytime the compiler can find a corresponding setter (`myMutableString.string = @"Excelsior!";`), but this is not so good for read-/maintain-ability.

Comment: Josh is right, it *works* on any parameterless method. It *should* only be used for *accessors*. I'd like to add that this includes not only methods defined with `@property`, but *also* any methods of the form `-property` and `-setProperty:`.