# How can I access a property with a string inside of dot notation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, properties

Check out the following code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *l112;
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *l212:
@property (weak, nonatomic) UILabel *l312:

((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).l112.text = @"Hello"
((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).l212.text = @"Hello"
((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).l312.text = @"Hello"
```

Notice how I'm setting all the text of my labels to "Hello".  There must be a more efficient way of doing this.  I am hoping I can somehow access the names of the UIlabels (l112, 1212, etc) to do so.  Does this make sense?  In my actual app, I'm not really setting everything to "Hello" but instead the the text is the result of a calculation.  Also, in my actual app I have more than 3 labels to set (there are 50+)  Here is my actual code using a repetitive if statement to access each UILabel sparately:

```
-(IBAction) submitScore: (id)sender
{
self.stringID = ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).self.giveString;

if (self.stringID isEqualToString:@"l112")
{ ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).l112.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", self.accumulator];} //l112 is the name of my UILabel
else if (self.stringID is EqualToString:@"l212")
{ ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).l212.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", self.accumulator];} //l212 is the name of my UILabel
}
```

I am wanting to be able to do it more efficiently like this:

```
-(IBAction) submitScore: (id)sender
 self.stringID = ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).self.giveString;

 ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController).[UILabel withTitle:@"%@",stringID].text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", self.accumulator];}
```

Notice my [UILabel withTitle: @"%@", stringID] part used within dot notation.  I know this doesn't work but I am wondering how I can write this correctly so stringID can be used to access the name of UILabel I need?

Comment: What's `+ [UILabel withTitle:]`?

Comment: You should use an NSArray, and have a search method that uses that array. NSArray of UI elements can be set from XIBs with `IBOutletCollection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers here deal with properties on objects. In this case you're trying to access the objects themselves. When you start asking yourself a question like this, you should just store all of the objects (in this case, labels), in an array property instead of individual properties for each label. Instead of thinking about/referencing labels as named variables like `l112`, think of them as indexes in the array:

> UILabel *theLabelINeed = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:2];
>   [theLabelINeed callWhateverMethodINeedTo];

Or shorter, if you're coming from a python/ruby background and this is more readable for you:

> [self.myArray[2] callWhateverMethodINeedTo];

And if you need to quickly access every label in the array, you can use fast enumeration in a for-loop:

```
for (UILabel *currLabel in self.myArray) {
    [currLabel callWhateverMethodINeedTo];
}
```

You could also use an `NSDictionary` instead, which lets you assign "keys" or names to objects.

```
NSDictionary *dict {"l112": label1, "l113": label2}; // or some other dictionary creation method, maybe a mutable dictionary or whatever.
UILabel *myLabel = [dict objectForKey:@"l112"];
```

Comment: I like the array idea.. Could I do this: 
 
[myLabelArray objectAtIndex:i].text = @"Whatever I need my text to be";

If all my objects in the array are UILabels, and UILabels have a text property, could I access the property as shown?

Comment: Sure! In your head you can sort of evaluate all the brackets down into what they return. So `objectAtIndex:` returns a `UILabel` and then you call `setText:` on the `UILabel` instance that's returned. If you end up using my answer don't forget to mark it as correct :)

Comment: I will try it out and see if this worthy of the check mark!  The NSDictionary options is looking pretty sexy as well. Thanks!

Comment: FYI: I used the array method and it worked like charm.  Thanks!  I couldn't use the [myLabelArray objectAtIndex:i].text or the .text property off a bracketed dict equivalent.  It said text property not found on object id.  I ended up needing to set an instance of my array and reference that in my code like this  myLabelArrayIntance.text

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! And yeah, I realized later you'd have to cast it and you couldn't use dot notation to do that: `[(UILabel *)[arr objectAtIndex:5] setText:@"myText"]`

Answer (score 5):

Try using `valueForKey:` on your UILabel.

However, a neater solution may be to simply store these properties in an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use dot notation - originally intended for object @properties - for something else ?

See [Dot Notation vs Method Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386256/dot-notation-vs-method-notation)

You seem confused by Objective-C syntax : Why `[UILabel withTitle:"%@", stringId]` instead of simpler `[UILabel withTitle:stringID]`, or if stringId isn't a string, `[UILabel withTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stringID]]`

Also, why is `withTitle` a class method on `UILabel` and not an instance method of your `presentingViewController` ?

Comment: ((RBScorecardVC *)self.presentingViewController)

Comment: Yes, so? `RBSscorecardVC` could very well have a `- (UILabel*)labelWithTitle:` instance method, no?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would probably do what you're asking, but I agree the answer using an NSDictionary is probably more maintainable. Alternatively, you could use the integer tag property on the labels in IB and call the parent view's viewWithTag: method.

```
- (UILabel *)labelWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(name);
    if (![self respondsToSelector:selector])
        return nil;

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    id result = [self performSelector:selector];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    if (!result)
        return nil;
    if (![result isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        return nil;
    return (UILabel *)result;
}

- (IBAction)derp:(id)sender
{
    UILabel *label = [self labelWithName:@"label1"];
    [label setText:@"I'm label 1"];
    label = [self labelWithName:@"label2"];
    [label setText:@"I'm label 2"];
}
```